# Sinatra cookies resetting between routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

so i'm trying to pass some strings through cookies between routes, but they keep getting reset and they don't get passed along.  here is my code:

```
post '/start_game' do
  @game = TicTacToe::Game.new
  cookies[:board] = @game.board.slots
  redirect '/game'
end

post '/game' do
  @slots = cookies[:board]
end
```

I've also tried request.cookies[:board], and even using quotes instead of using symbols.

Comment: How are you setting up the cookies? are you requiring the helpers with : `require "sinatra/cookies"` ?

Comment: yes, installed the Sinatra Contrib

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are setting a cookie on one path and reading it on a different one. `/start_game` is considered to be a different part of your site to `/game` from a cookie point of view. You can solve this problem by setting the cookie at the `/` level:

```
response.set_cookie(:board, { :path => '/' })
```

You should not need to change the way that you read it back (because any other path is a sub-path of `/`).